# Jest test of React component's setState update from within a Promise

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Given a React component called `ListContainer` with a function to load data as so:

```
loadList() {
    this.setState({loading: true});

    return this.props.api.get({
        sort: this.props.sort.order,
        search: this.props.search.query,
        limit: this.props.pager.limit,
        offset: this.props.pager.offset
    }).then((response: ApiResponse) => {
        this.setState({
            listItems: response.data.records,
            itemCount: response.data.meta.count,
            error: undefined
        })
    }).catch((error: ApiError) => {
        this.setState({
            error: error
        })
    }).then(() => {
        this.setState({
            loading: false
        })
    })
}
```

I'm attempting to write a test that will ensure that the response data will be written to the component's state.

```
test('loads list items', () => {
        const testApi = {
            get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
        };

        // Omitting some additional props for brevity.
        wrapper = shallow(<ListContainer api={testApi}/>);

        const testItems = [
            'Test Item 1',
            'Test Item 2',
        ];

        testApi.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
            Promise.resolve({
                data: {records: testItems}
            })
        );

        return wrapper.instance().loadList()
            .then(() => {
                expect(wrapper.update().state().listItems).toBe(testItems)
            });
    })
```

I can see that my mock is returning the test data correctly (via `console.log(response)` in the `loadList` function) however the test is still failing. How do I ensure that `setState` has completed before asserting my expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close!

You just need to add `.data.meta.count` to your response mock, right now the code ends up throwing an error since it isn't included in the current mock.

Just change your mock to this:

```
testApi.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    data: {
      records: testItems,
      meta: { count: 2 }  // <= include .data.meta.count
    }
  })
);
```

...and that should fix it!

Comment: Duh! Thanks so much!